# List All Partitions On Disk

Tags: c#, .net, disk-partitioning

I'm making a utility in C# for a filesystem that isn't supported by windows, which means that  I can't just access the drive. I need a way to list all partitions on the hard disk and writing/formatting them.

Comment: Not being able to access the drive doesn't leave you with much beyond make a photo of it.

Comment: @HansPassant I think he means drive as in 'C: drive' and 'D: drive', not as in 'hard disk drive'.

Comment: @CommunistPancake Please ask the question, improve and paste some code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To list disk partitions you can use WMI.

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskPartition");

foreach (var queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Win32_DiskPartition instance");
    Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}", (string)queryObj["Name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Index:{0}", (uint)queryObj["Index"]);
    Console.WriteLine("DiskIndex:{0}", (uint)queryObj["DiskIndex"]);
    Console.WriteLine("BootPartition:{0}", (bool)queryObj["BootPartition"]);
}
```

Comment: hi how can i get partition Caption (C,D,E,...) from this class?

Comment: I found this to be useful:  
    https://gist.github.com/MiloszKrajewski/352dc8b8eb132d3a2bc7        You'll want to un-comment the commented-out write()'s for full info

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach to get the Volume or DriveLetter on which the partition of disk is mounted.

1. Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition
2. Win32_DiskDrive

From the `Win32_DiskDrive` class you can get the `DriveNumber` by querying property `Index` or extracting the `DriveNumber` from `Name` attribute. Then query `Antecedent` and `Dependent` from  `Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition`. In the `Antecedent` value you will get the Disk Number and the partition it is trying to map the Volume, after that extract the `DriveLetter` such as "C:", "D:" etc from the `Dependent` property. So by using this logic you can get the `LogicalDrives` mounted on particular `HardDisk`.
I'm using this logic in my component to get the `LogicalDrive` names ("C:", "D:" etc) for particular hard drive on my system.

Comment: Some sample code would be nice