# Tell if a Drive is a partition or a separate HDD

Tags: c#, windows, file-io

I am writing my own file search (why because I want to / can - not looking for an existing program). I can get all the drives in c# by using the [DriveInfo.GetDrives()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx) method. Ideally I would like to run the search in parallel only on drives that are separate disk and for partitions that are on the same drive run them sequential. This way I will not cause the drives on constantly seek as the GetDrives returns all partitions or removable media. I know I can tell the type if it is a USB Drives vs. a HDD? How can I accomplish this will the DriveInfo or any other methodology that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575727/list-all-partitions-on-disk) shows how to find out using WMI (found in `System.Management`):

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskPartition");

foreach (var queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Win32_DiskPartition instance");
    Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}", (string)queryObj["Name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Index:{0}", (uint)queryObj["Index"]);
    Console.WriteLine("DiskIndex:{0}", (uint)queryObj["DiskIndex"]);
    Console.WriteLine("BootPartition:{0}", (bool)queryObj["BootPartition"]);
}
```

Comment: So the DiskIndex is the physical drive?

Comment: From the [documentation for Win32_DiskPartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394135(v=vs.85).aspx), DiskIndex is "Index number of the disk containing this partition."

Comment: @Brad - Has the solution provided not worked for you? (You took away the answer...)

Comment: How can you map the the Index to the Volume i.e C:\ is Index 0 on DiskIndex 0?

Comment: That should be a question for a *different* question... I've answered the question presented here.

Comment: @M.Babcok Alright Ill create a different question but part of my solution was using the GetDrives which only has the volume label (the Name property). I thought the method would allow based on the Name and other properties but I was misinformed by my own reading. That is why I had marked it unanswers.