# Map a DiskIndex to a Volume Label

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, system.management, driveinfo

Current I am able to get all the Drives and their labels in c# by using the [DriveInfo.GetDrives()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx). Then I am able to get the Disk Index / Index of the Partition by this methodology.

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskPartition");

foreach (var queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Win32_DiskPartition instance");
    Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}", (string)queryObj["Name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Index:{0}", (uint)queryObj["Index"]);
    Console.WriteLine("DiskIndex:{0}", (uint)queryObj["DiskIndex"]);
    Console.WriteLine("BootPartition:{0}", (bool)queryObj["BootPartition"]);
}
```

The problem with this is that the DiskIndex, Name, and Index are basically just numbers and not the Volume Label i.e. C:\, D:\, etc...

So bottom line how can I make the Volume Label which is the [Name Proprty on the DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.name.aspx) to the DiskIndex? Either using this methodology or a better way will work.

(This is a follow to: [Tell if a Drive is a partition or a separate HDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114078/tell-if-a-drive-is-a-partition-or-a-seperate-hdd/9114165#9114165))

**EDIT:**
I did find for the Management Query of the [Win32_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then the [Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  the LogicalDisk has the volume and the LogicalDisktoParition provides the mapping. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get the map. I tried looking for a JOIN and selecting the values but couldn't find anything on how do this join without extensive looping in the c# code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [Win32_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

Edit: You are correct [Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Is the link between [Win32_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Win32_DiskPartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  On [Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, these two properties show the links,

PS> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition

Antecedent       : \\computer\root\cimv2:**Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #1"**

Dependent        : \\computer\root\cimv2:**Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="D:"**

Just parse these two properties and filter the the other classes appropriately.

Comment: See my Edit that I just added.

Comment: I was thinking about the solution but is there a way to do the query. I mean I see the SELECT * FROM and think hey that like SQL just essentially "JOIN" the "Tables". So It would be something like SELECT Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID, Win32_DiskPartition.DiskIndex FROM Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition INNER JOIN ... you get the picture.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no join construct in WQL.  You could just select everything from each WMI class and use LINQ to do the join.  You would have to parse the Antecedent / Dependent propety values.  Luckily, the number of partitions and volumes you have will be fairly small.

Comment: I appreciate the straight-forwardness of this answer.

Answer (score 6):

some time ago i had same problem and i do it with these code :

```
ListViewGroup hddgrp;
                lstHDD.Columns.Add("Disk");
                lstHDD.Columns.Add("Patition");
                lstHDD.Columns.Add("Free Space");
                lstHDD.Columns.Add("Total Space");

                lstHDD.View = View.Details;
                String DiskName = "";
                String PartState = "";
                String PartName = "";
                String PartFree = "";
                ManagementObjectSearcher hdd = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive");
                foreach (ManagementObject objhdd in hdd.Get())
                {
                    PartState = "";
                    DiskName = "Disk " + objhdd["Index"].ToString() + " : " + objhdd["Caption"].ToString().Replace(" ATA Device", "") +
                        " (" + Math.Round( Convert.ToDouble(objhdd["Size"]) / 1073741824,1) + " GB)";
                    hddgrp = lstHDD.Groups.Add(DiskName, DiskName);
                    ObjCount = Convert.ToInt16(objhdd["Partitions"]);
                    ManagementObjectSearcher partitions = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                        "Select * From Win32_DiskPartition Where DiskIndex='" + objhdd["Index"].ToString() + "'");
                    foreach(ManagementObject part in partitions.Get())
                    {
                        PartName = part["DeviceID"].ToString();
                        if (part["Bootable"].ToString() == "True" && part["BootPartition"].ToString() == "True")
                            PartState = "Recovery";
                        else
                        {
                            ManagementObjectSearcher getdisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher
                                ("Select * From Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition Where  ");
                            PartState = GetPartName(PartName);
                            PartFree = GetFreeSpace(PartState);
                            PartState = "Local Disk (" + PartState + ")";
                        }

                        lstHDD.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new String[] { "Partition " + part["Index"].ToString(),
                            PartState,PartFree ,Math.Round( Convert.ToDouble(part["Size"].ToString()) / 1073741824,1) + " GB"}, hddgrp));
                    }
                }
                lstHDD.Columns[0].Width = 80;
                lstHDD.Columns[1].Width = 120;
                lstHDD.Columns[2].Width = 100;
                lstHDD.Columns[3].Width = 100;
```

and two sub method :

```
private String GetFreeSpace(String inp)
        {
            String totalspace = "", freespace = "", freepercent = "";
            Double sFree = 0, sTotal = 0, sEq = 0;
            ManagementObjectSearcher getspace = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk Where DeviceID='" + inp +"'");
            foreach (ManagementObject drive in getspace.Get())
            {
                if (drive["DeviceID"].ToString() == inp)
                {
                    freespace = drive["FreeSpace"].ToString();
                    totalspace = drive["Size"].ToString();
                    sFree = Convert.ToDouble(freespace);
                    sTotal = Convert.ToDouble(totalspace);
                    sEq = sFree * 100 / sTotal;
                    freepercent = (Math.Round((sTotal - sFree) / 1073741824, 2)).ToString() + " (" + Math.Round(sEq,0).ToString() + " %)";
                    return freepercent;
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
        private String GetPartName(String inp)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(inp);
            String Dependent = "", ret = "";
            ManagementObjectSearcher LogicalDisk = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition");
            foreach (ManagementObject drive in LogicalDisk.Get())
            {
                if (drive["Antecedent"].ToString().Contains(inp))
                {
                    Dependent = drive["Dependent"].ToString();
                    ret = Dependent.Substring(Dependent.Length - 3, 2);
                    break;
                }

            }
            return ret;

        }
```

I hope this solution be useful.
for me this result is as below picture
[image: Hard Disks Informations]

Comment: Thanks. But what is lstHDD? Is it a listView?