# Listing all disk partitions in C#

Tags: c#, wmi

I've been writing a code for listing all the partitions of a disk and I've found a problem. The `Win32_DiskDrive` property `Partitions` of WMI show me that one test disk have 5 partitions, but I can only list four of them (the last two partitions appear as they were only one). These last two partitions are primary, but one is a SWAP partition and the other is a Linux partition.

Comment: Can we see the code you have tried?

Comment: @KenWhite, I would agree only if the OP actually wants to use the WMI approach, rather than Tim's answer.

Comment: I've tried this code
`code`var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskPartition);<br/>
foreach (var queryObj in searcher.Get())<br/>
{<br/>
  Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");<br/>
  Console.WriteLine("Win32_DiskPartition instance");<br/>
  Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}", (string)queryObj["Name"]);<br/>
  Console.WriteLine("Index:{0}", (uint)queryObj["Index"]);<br/>
  Console.WriteLine("DeviceID:{0}", (string)queryObj["DeviceID"]);<br/>
}`

Comment: @gunr2171: The question asks about listing all disk partitions in C#, which is what the question I linked asks as well. Neither of them says "Without WMI", and this question indeed mentions using WMI. Nowhere does this question say "using Tim's answer" either. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the trick:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads all Drives of the Computer and returns a List.
    /// </summary>
    private List<DriveInfo> LoadDrives()
    {
        var drives = new List<DriveInfo>();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (drive.IsReady)
            {
                drives.Add(drive);
            }
        }
        return drives;
    }
```

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could replace your `drives.Add` with a `yield return` and return an `IEnumerable`. Just as suggestion.

Comment: I tried it, but this code returns only 3 drives, and the windows disk management shows 5...

Comment: Yeah, that's true and maybe more elegant :)

Comment: I think is reason might be the conditional!
You could Debug the function and see why only three Drives are returned!

Comment: DriveInfo.GetDrives() only return the same drives that Windows shows in My PC window

Comment: Maybe there are any Attributes set for the other two drives? My windows shows my one additional Drive on the partitions - window.
So, maybe the two drives don't have a drive-letter accociated?

Comment: Yes, the two drives don´t have a drive-letter associated because they are Linux and Swap partitions, and Windows can´t see it.

Comment: You can also try out this solution, it sounds like it may solve your problem, but I didn't test it!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575727/list-all-partitions-on-disk?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I already knew that link and I tried that solution, but it only show me 4 partitions, the last partition shown has got the same size that the last two real partitions...

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is [`string[] System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives()`](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1371580232&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=http%3a%2f%2fmsdn.microsoft.com%2fen-us%2flibrary%2fsystem.io.directory.getlogicaldrives.aspx&lc=1033&id=254354&mkt=en-US).

For each `string` you get using `GetLogicalDrives`, you can create a [`System.IO.DriveInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.driveinfo.aspx) object, which will provide all kinds of information about the logical drive.

[`DriveInfo.GetDrives()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx) may be a shortcut to the two steps given above. I'm not entirely sure of that though, and the documentation isn't very clear.

Comment: I'll try with `string[] System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives()` and I'll tell my experience

Comment: This code return the same, only 3 drives, the same drives that Windows shows in My Computer window...