# is there any c# class which can be use to retrieve total number of hard disk partitions or other information ?

Tags: c#

i need to retrieve HDD related information like total number of partitions,in which driver OS is installed etc. programmatically in c#.any one here to help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List All Partitions On Disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575727/list-all-partitions-on-disk)

Comment: This may be helpful: [How to I retrieve disk information in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/412632/646543)

Comment: Check the `Environment` class for the answers on some parts of your question.

Comment: thanku guys :) i'll look upon above mentioned links

Answer (score 1):

You can get available HDD related information from:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28VS.85%29.aspx)

sample:

```
ManagementClass sampleClass= new ManagementClass("Win32_DiskDrive");
ManagementObjectCollection SampleDrive= driveClass.GetInstances();
string Information="";
foreach (ManagementObject drives in SampleDrive) 
{ 

    foreach (PropertyData HDDproperty in drives .Properties)
    {
        Information +="HDDProperty: {0}, HDDValue: {1}", HDDproperty .Name, HDDproperty .Value);        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For most information, you can use the DriveInfo class.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Info {
    public static void Main() {
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives) {
            //There are more attributes you can use.
            //Check the MSDN link for a complete example.
            Console.WriteLine(drive.Name);
            if (drive.IsReady) Console.WriteLine(drive.TotalSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**WMI to rescue**

You can use WMI queries to fetch information about system.

[Example to fetch OS information related to OS](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CCS-LABS-WMI-Extended-OS-be252a4e)

[Other WMI samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B0%5D.Value=C%23&f%5B0%5D.Text=C%23&f%5B1%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B1%5D.Value=wmi&sortBy=Relevance)