# Get disk partitions

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get all partitions available in my system . This code just return one partition .

```
string[] arr = new string[4];
ListViewItem itm;
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
    if (d.IsReady == true)
    {
        arr[0] = d.Name;
        arr[1] = d.DriveType.ToString();
        arr[2] = d.TotalSize.ToString();
        arr[3] = d.DriveFormat;
        itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
        listView1.Items.Add(itm);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: try using [GetLogicalDrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)... i.e. `Directory.GetLogicalDrives()`

Comment: That code doesn't return _any_ partitions. It returns a disk drive. It will not return a partition which is not mounted as a drive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List All Partitions On Disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575727/list-all-partitions-on-disk)

Comment: You should create a new array every time, otherwise all the items will show the same informations (i.e. those of the last drive)

Comment: WMI Is the way to do it. The link that @huMptyduMpty commented on will do what you need