# List Of Hard Disks and drives on them

Tags: c#

how can i get a list of hard disks and their partitions(their logical drives) on my computer  in c#?
iam looking for code that gives me similar results

harddisk0:partitions are C,D

harddisk1:partitions are C,F,D

i have tried this code

```
foreach (ManagementObject drive in search.Get())
{
   string antecedent = drive["DeviceID"].ToString(); 
   // the disk we're trying to find out about
   antecedent = antecedent.Replace(@"\", "\\"); 
   // this is just to escape the slashes
   string query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" 
                     + antecedent 
                     + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
   using (ManagementObjectSearcher partitionSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
      {
         foreach (ManagementObject part in partitionSearch.Get())
         {
            //...pull out the partition information
            Console.WriteLine("Dependent : {0}", part["Dependent"]);
          }
       }
}
```

knowing that dependent is a Reference to the instance representing the disk partition residing on the disk drive.
but iam getting the exception Not Found

what should i write please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List All Partitions On Disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575727/list-all-partitions-on-disk)

Comment: no my problem wasn't solved from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575727/list-all-partitions-on-disk

Comment: it was solved by getting the plan from this script
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/05/23/how-can-i-correlate-logical-drives-and-physical-disks/

Answer (score 2):

here is c# solution generated by me

```
    foreach (ManagementObject drive in search.Get())
            {

                string antecedent = drive["DeviceID"].ToString(); // the disk we're trying to find out about
                antecedent = antecedent.Replace(@"\", "\\"); // this is just to escape the slashes
                string query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + antecedent + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
                using (ManagementObjectSearcher partitionSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
                {
                    foreach (ManagementObject part in partitionSearch.Get())
                    {
                        //...pull out the partition information
                        MessageBox.Show(part["DeviceID"].ToString());
                        query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + part["DeviceID"] + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition";
                        using (ManagementObjectSearcher logicalpartitionsearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
                            foreach (ManagementObject logicalpartition in logicalpartitionsearch.Get())
                            MessageBox.Show(logicalpartition["DeviceID"].ToString());
                    }

                }
            }
```

the plan of this code is described in this script https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/05/23/how-can-i-correlate-logical-drives-and-physical-disks/